# How to use HttpClient.PutAsJsonAsync()

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a c# project with a RESTfull client and RESTfull server. I am unable to get `PUT` request to work. I think I am maybe not using `PutAsJsonAsync()` correctly.

The client...

```
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.Net.Http.Formatting;

        public class RequestParams {
             public String param1 { get; set;}
        }


        fullUrl = "http://localhost:3578/api/v1.0/config";
        client = new HttpClient();
        var requestParams = new RequestParams {
            parm1 = "value1"
        };
        response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(fullUrl, requestParams).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The server (nancy self hosting)...

```
        Put["/api/v1.0/config"] = x =>
        {
                NameValueCollection requestParams =
                    HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Body.AsString());
                Console.WriteLine("requestParams=" + requestParams);
                var param1 = requestParams["param1"];
```

At the server side I get for the requestParams...

```
{"param1":"value1"}={"param1":"value1"}
```

I have confirmed that the server is working by using a python client. I get for requestParams...

```
param1=value1
```

Comment: `I am unable to get PUT request to work` So, How about sharing exceptions you get? :))

Comment: @Eser, I dont get any exceptions, I just get the wrong thing received at the server:: `{"param1":"value1"}={"param1":"value1"}`. The code above is cut down for brevity. Do you want me to upload compilable c# code?